# How can I identify the manufacturer of my walk in bathtub?

Tags: bathtub

I saw another post that said there should be access to the electric panel, but I don’t see anything like that. Is there any other way to find out who made the tub?

Comment: Does the tub have electrical equipment in it? Check for a label on the door edge or stampings in hinge hardware, etc.

Comment: I’m not able to see any electrical equipment. It might be in a place where it’s inaccessible? I have checked literally everywhere for any kind of label or stamp but I see nothing. Does it seem that there’s probably no way for me to find out what it is without help from a professional?

Comment: You don't need a professional to use Google. Post a few clear photos.